# Adding on_release action to buttons in loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

```
class WidgetFiscal(Screen):
    box = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_box(self, *args):
        fiscal = ['Elzab Mera TE FV', 'Posnet Thermal XL', 'Posnet HD', 'Elzab Sigma', 'Novitus Delio Prime E', 'Elzab D10', 'Posnet Trio', 'Epson TM-T801FV']
        for i in fiscal:
            self.box.add_widget(Button(text=str(i), background_color=[1,2,1,1]))
```

my .kv file :

```
<FiscalPrinter>:
    name: 'fiscal_printer'

    BoxLayout:
        size: root.size
        spacing: 20
        padding: 10,10,10,10
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: 'Choose fiscal printer which you want to rent'
            size: root.width, root.height / 10
            size_hint: None, None

        WidgetFiscal:

        Button:
            text: 'GO BACK'
            size: root.width, root.height / 10
            size_hint: None, None
            on_release: app.root.current = "rent_device"

<WidgetFiscal>:
    box: box

    GridLayout:
        background_color: 1,2,1,1
        cols: 3
        id: box
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `on_release` event to `Button` widget.

```
self.box.add_widget(Button(..., on_release=self.mycallback))
```

## Notes

[Kivy » Touch event basics](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/inputs.html#touch-event-basics)

> By default, touch events are dispatched to all currently displayed
>   widgets. This means widgets receive the touch event whether it occurs
>   within their physical area or not.
>
> ...
>
> In order to provide the maximum flexibility, Kivy dispatches the
>   events to all the widgets and lets them decide how to react to them.
>   If you only want to respond to touch events inside the widget, you
>   simply check:
>
> ```
> def on_touch_down(self, touch):
>     if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
>         # The touch has occurred inside the widgets area. Do stuff!
>         pass
> ```

## Solution

Therefore you want to define `class PrinterButton` with inheritance of `Button` widget and implement `on_touch_down` method to only respond to touch events for `Button` touched.

### Snippets

```
class PrinterButton(Button):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            print(f"\nPrinterButton.on_touch_down: text={self.text}")
            self.dispatch('on_release')
            return True    # consumed on_touch_down & stop propagation / bubbling
        return super(PrinterButton, self).on_touch_down(touch)

class WidgetFiscal(Screen): 
    box = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_box(self, *args):
        fiscal = ['Elzab Mera TE FV', 'Posnet Thermal XL', 'Posnet HD', 'Elzab Sigma', 'Novitus Delio Prime E', 'Elzab D10', 'Posnet Trio', 'Epson TM-T801FV']
        for i in fiscal:
            self.box.add_widget(PrinterButton(text=str(i), background_color=[1,2,1,1], on_release=self.mycallback))

    def mycallback(self, instance):
        print(f"mycallback: Button.text={instance.text}")
```

## Output

[image: Result]